# Query pyarrow dataset from GCP bucket is extremely slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyarrow

I am using pyarrow dataset to Query a parquet file in GCP, the code is straightforward

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import duckdb
import json
lineitem = ds.dataset("gs://duckddelta/lineitem",format="parquet")
lineitem_partition = ds.dataset("gs://duckddelta/delta2",format="parquet", partitioning="hive")
con = duckdb.connect()
def Query(request):
    SQL = request.get_json().get('name')
    df = con.execute(SQL).df()
    return json.dumps(df.to_json(orient="records")), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

then I call that function using a SQL Query

```
SQL = '''
    SELECT
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus,
    SUM(l_quantity) AS sum_qty,
    SUM(l_extendedprice) AS sum_base_price,
    SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) AS sum_disc_price,
    SUM(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) * (1 + l_tax)) AS sum_charge,
    AVG(l_quantity) AS avg_qty,
    AVG(l_extendedprice) AS avg_price,
    AVG(l_discount) AS avg_disc,
    COUNT(*) AS count_order
FROM
    lineitem 
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2 ;
    '''
```

I know that local SSD storage is faster but I am getting some massive difference

The Query take 4 second, when the file is saved in my laptop
it take 54 second when run from google cloud function in the same region
take 3 minutes when I run it in Colab
it seems to me there is a bottleneck somewhere in google cloud function, I was expected a better performance

edit for more context : File is 1.2 GB, region is us-central1 (Iowa), cloud function gen 2, 8 GB, 8 CPU

Comment: How large is the Cloud Storage object (in bytes)? What are the regions for storage and the function? How is the function configured? Edit your question with details.

Answer (score 0):

sorry turn out it is a possible bug in DuckDB, apparently it DuckDB is not multi threaded in this particular scenario
https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/4525